# Jespa 1.1 Java + ActiveDirectory NTLM auth does not work

Tags: java, windows-7, ntlm, jespa

http://www.ioplex.com/jespa.html

I am following the example as described in **Providing NTLM Services without Active Directory** part of the **documentation**, and deploying the examples war into JBoss

I did:

- Increase all JBoss port numbers by 1000 (so I am using port 9080 )
- Rename example_ntsp_web.xml into web.xml
- And then deploy.
- I could not get auth'ed

When I debugged into JBoss, it is failing at comparing the ntlm objects

```
 NtlmResponse local = new NtlmResponse(resp,domain, myusername,mypassword.toCharArray(), getTargetInformation());

 if (resp.equals(local)) {            <--------------------- fails here, resp and local not equal
```

}

Debugging info using eclipse, ntResponses length are not equal between local and resp ?

[image]

What else am I missing?

Environment:
- Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new alpha release of jespa 1.1.4b http://www.ioplex.com/d/jespa-1.1.4b.zip this problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to check

- Are you logged in to your Windows 7 box with the account `admin` and password `opensaysme`?
- Does your Windows 7 domain match whats configured in your plaintext file?

You could also try emailing IOPlex directly, I found them very responsive in the past.

Comment: IOPlex did respond very quickly, and we narrowed it down to Windows7 being "different" (as per my answer above)